# Diferença entre chamar a chamada do fragment e uma nova instância

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Estou trabalhando em um projeto da faculdade onde fiz um aplicativo que usa fragments. Estive sempre acostumado a criar um fragment da seguinte maneira:

```
// imports

...

public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {
    public LoginFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Porém vi que o Android Studio dá uma opção de criar um fragment em branco, com o seguinte código:

```
// imports 

...

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link BlankFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;


    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment BlankFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static BlankFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ((FservActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Chamados");
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    }


}
```

O que eu gostaria de saber é: como eu faço para chamar uma instância do fragment (usando o `newInstance`)? Qual é a diferença prática entre eu chamar uma nova instância e eu chamar um novo fragment (`new BlankFragment`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A forma de se inicializar um novo fragmento com argumentos é guardá-los em um `Bundle` e passar esse `Bundle` para o fragmento via `setArguments(Bundle)`. Dessa forma os argumentos passados por você serão preservados entre destruições e recriações do fragmento pelo próprio sistema Android.

Em geral porém você irá querer simplificar a ação de guardar argumentos em um `Bundle` e passá-lo via `setArguments()` aos seus fragmentos. Inicialmente podemos pensar que a forma de se fazer isso é encapsular esse comportamento em uma versão de construtor sobrecarregada para receber argumentos.

Porém, criar um construtor com argumentos não é uma opção viável porque quando o Android decide recriar seu fragmento ele tem por comportamento chamar a versão sem argumentos do construtor:

```
Fragment.instantiate(context, MeuFragmento.class.getName(), meuBundle)
```

Com isso, a forma recomendada de simplificar a passagem de argumentos é encapsulando-a dentro de um método estático `newInstance(argumento1, argumento2, ...)`.

Feito isso, a instanciação de um fragmento usando `newInstance()` não tem segredos. Ao invés de fazer:

```
MeuFragmento fragmento = new MeuFragmento(argumento1, argumento2);
```

...você o faz chamando o método estático:

```
MeuFragmento fragmento = MeuFragmento.newInstance(argumento1, argumento2);
```

Como você pode perceber, `newInstance(arg1, arg2, ...)` é útil somente se o seu fragmento recebe argumentos; se ele não recebe nenhum argumento, então não há necessidade de se criar um método `newInstance()` sem argumentos.

*(Respondido com trechos [desta pergunta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment))*